# c++ new and delete overloading

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

`new` and `delete` operator overloading might or might not work when compiled using different compilers and different c++ standards. Is that the normal behavior?

I used the following code to test the compilers.

```
#include <iostream>

void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "1\n";
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "2\n";
    free(ptr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *n1 = new int;
    delete n1;

    int *n2 = new int[10];
    delete[] n2;

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results I got from several compilers I have tested the code on.

mingw-w64 official build - x86_64-7.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0.7z

```
c++11
1
2

c++14
1
```

clang x86_64 - v4.0.0 manually built without patches using the compiler above

```
c++11 and c++14
1
2
```

msvc - platform toolset v141 & sdk v10.0.15063.0

```
/std:c++14 and /std:c++latest
1
2
1
2
```

All tests are performed on Windows 7. I can't test compilers on GNU/Linux OS because I don't have any VMs set up.

Comment: Where in your example does it not work?

Comment: You need to overload the [] version(s):  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new  And the signatures have changed with standard changes, testing different compilers on different standard(s) will give different results.

Comment: @RichardCritten There is no need to even overload the [] operator on the msvc compiler. See the msvc result above.

Comment: Yes I saw that - looking into that now.

Comment: The array form calls the non-array form (ie your overload): _"2) Called by the array form of new[]-expressions to allocate all storage required for an array (including possible new-expression overhead). The standard library implementation calls version (1) [non-array]"_  from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new So my reading is MSVC is the more correct here  Add and instrument the array version please.

Comment: GCC 6.3 behaves the same way as msvc: http://ideone.com/N7wJhQ

Comment: The mingw c++14 behavior looks a bit alarming...

Comment: @aschepler Yea, memory leaking everywhere or crashing when the operators are overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

By the standard, the default behavior of both `operator new[]` is ([new.delete.array]/4):

> Returns `operator new(size)`, or `operator new(size, alignment)`, respectively.

Something similar goes for `operator delete[]` ([new.delete.array]/15):

> The functions that have a `size` parameter forward their other parameters to the corresponding function without a `size` parameter. The functions that do not have a `size` parameter forward their parameters to the corresponding `operator delete` (single-object) function.

The default versions of these functions simply call the non-array forms. Therefore, Visual Studio and GCC 6.3 are correct: overloading just the non-array versions should be enough to overload the allocators.